# Multi Level Slidiing Panel (Angular)

Tags: angularjs, panel, slide

I'm trying to create a sliding side panel using angularJS (hint: I'm a newbie).

What I need to do is to activate another panel from within another panel (via a link or a button inside that panel).

And the that new panel may also contain another button or link that will open another panel ad infinitum.

So far I've tried https://github.com/dpiccone/ng-pageslide and http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngAside but I'm not sure how to do what I want to do.

I'm trying to achieve something like this here:http://metricslice.com/blog/2014/05/15/flyouts-as-a-web-pattern/

Anybody out there with a more effective tip to point me in the right direction?

Comment: so you want a slidein side bar that just changes from a bar to a content?

Comment: Basically. I want another sidebar sliding in over the currently opened sidebar. Its use case would be on mobile devices. Ultimately, I want that sidebar to cover around 95% of the screen.

Comment: so infact you want a togglable side bar with a changeable view so at first it shows the actions and then it changes the view to the items clicked?

Comment: Yes, but I also want the new view to have that sliding effect essentially like a 'card' going over another 'card', if you get my meaning.

Comment: so? just have a side bar that has nested views in it, if you use ui-router its very simple, and each new view has a class with the slide animation... so you create a side bar, put some placeholder or ui-routers ui-view tag in it then just either have it in a different module or just create a routing system for this flow and on each load you can have a class that does the  slide animation.